# В функции не работает корректно деление */*, подскажите пожалуйста из за чего

Tags: php

```
<?php
function calculate($array_with_numbers, $doit) {
    echo "<h3>".calculate . " $doit</h3><br>";
    if(is_array($array_with_numbers)) {
        $restore = 0;
        switch($doit) {
            case '+':
                foreach ($array_with_numbers as $number) $restore += $number;
                break;
            case '-':
                foreach ($array_with_numbers as $number) $restore -= $number;
                break;
            case '*':
                $restore = 1;
                foreach ($array_with_numbers as $number) $restore *= $number;
                break;
            case '/':
                $restore = $array_with_numbers[0];
                for ($i = 1; $i < count($array_with_numbers); $i++)
                    if ($array_with_numbers[$i] != 0)
                        $restore /= $array_with_numbers[$i];
                break;
            case '%':
                $restore = $array_with_numbers[0];
                for ($i = 1; $i < count($array_with_numbers); $i++)
                    if ($array_with_numbers[$i] != 0)
                        $restore %= $array_with_numbers[$i];
                break;
            default:
                echo "I can`t do it :(<br>";
        }
        echo $restore . "<br>";
    }
    else
        echo "you've done something nasty buddy";
}




function arif(){
    $arrayArg=func_get_args();
    $act=func_get_arg(0);
    unset($arrayArg[0]);
    calculate($arrayArg, $act);


}
arif('/',100,8);

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После `unset($arrayArg[0]);` ваш массив теряет элемент `[0]`, и остаётся с элементами `[1]` и `[2]` – их индексы не меняются.

А в обработке деления вы ожидаете, что `$array_with_numbers` будет содержать числа, начиная с 0-го элемента. В этом суть ошибки.

**Починить** легко: вместо `unset()` используйте [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-shift.php).

Кроме того, у вас бардак в строке `echo..`.

Comment: отлично Спасибо! Коротко и дельно , все заработало..